# Java Spring REST and Hibernate JPA - http 400 while PUT entity twice

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am writing my own app using spring mvc (restful webservice) and hibernate. 
The problem is, that I have my method in controller that is mapped to url: PUT /report/

and now, in the request body I send the JSON representation of Report entity. When I run the server, add some entities and then try to edit one, the first attempt succeed but the second and every next fails and returns http 400 code.
So it acts like it could be edited just once? strange

Here is my code:

REPOSITORY:

```
@Repository
public class ReportHibernateRepository implements ReportRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    //.......other methods............
    @Override
    public Report update(Report report) {
        Report report1 = entityManager.find(Report.class, report.getId());
        report1.setDate(report.getDate());
        report1.setReporter(report.getReporter());
        report1.setReportText(report.getReportText());
        report1.setTitle(report.getTitle());
        return report1;
    }
}
```

SERVICE:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ReportService {
    @Autowired
    private ReportRepository reportRepository;

    //..........other methods...........    
    public Report update(Report report){
        return reportRepository.update(report);
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/report")
public class ReportController {
    @Autowired
    private ReportService reportService;

    //.........other methods...........
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void update(@RequestBody Report report){
        reportService.update(report);
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what's the problem?

Comment: First things first. Shouldn't you PUT with an ID? `PUT /report/1234`? For creating new entities without an id use `POST`. Also, are there any exception being logged on the server?

Comment: yes I should and I am going to change it soon(I will ignore the ID from json and rely only on the one from url), but first I have to figure out why does it not want to edit my entities :P unfortunatelly there is no log in my IDE

Comment: everything i got is this: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (). Looks like my JSON is wrong, but just by the second attempt? thought its the same

Comment: you mean, system out println in controller?

Comment: Yes, or properly enable logging so that we don't have to resort to something so ugly hehehe :).

Comment: I use IntelliJ and neither RUN bookmark, nor event log, nor terminal nor anything shows more than this that I wrote upper. It is shown in IntelliJ rest client in response bookmark

Comment: You can start your server through IntelliJ and it will show server logs (at least mine does).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly i have added println to controller and if you need my full server log, here is it: http://pastebin.com/WsQWjTmS

Comment: From logs everything seems to be alright (it is inserting the report entity once; selecting it back and updating it without logging any exceptions, unless if they happened after the event). Maybe the problem is the empty `reporter` / `null reporter_id` thing. Is your relationship optional? Is your FK column `NOT NULL`? What is Hibernate feeding `reporter_id` with?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly actually there is nothing that tells report entity that reporter musnt be null. I think its optional. Maybe I will give you my both entities ;) here they are: http://pastebin.com/mmUkGgjy

Comment: Could you please share your Report  class if problem still exists.